# How to delete Certain Characters in a excel 2010 cell

Tags: excel, character, excel-2010, cell

In column A I have a load of name that look like this

[John Smith]

I still want them in A but the [] removed...

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE( text, old_text, new_text, [nth_appearance] )` i.e `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[",""),"]","")`

Answer (score 27):

If `[John Smith]` is in cell A1, then use this formula to do what you want:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "[", ""), "]", "")
```

The inner SUBSTITUTE replaces all instances of "[" with "" and returns a new string, then the other SUBSTITUTE replaces all instances of "]" with "" and returns the final result.

Comment: If I want to remove only one occurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Replace [ with nothing, then ] with nothing.

Comment: This would be my answer too. It is faster than any of the answers above.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:
`=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)`

Or this (for fun):
`=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))-1)`